# How show registers in HTML table without reload the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm developing a website using asp.net and C#, and I'm registering new users, but when I'm trying to add many telephones to this user in the table doesn't show me the new register until I press the register button again but it register twice but only show one, could you help me with this?

This is the code from the asp.net

I charge the table using `<asp:Literal ID="tablaTel" runat="server"></asp:Literal>`

```html
<div class="panel panel-default letra" id="panelTelefonos">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <!--INICIO TITULO DE PANEL TELEFONOS-->
            <div class="row text-left">
                <label class="control-label" for="txtRegRecNombre">
                    <span class="form-text">TELEFONOS DE CONTACTO:</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <!--FIN TITULO DE PANEL TELEFONOS-->
            <!--INICIO PRIMERA FILA TELEFONOS-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <label class="control-label" for="DdTelefonos">
                         <span class="form-text">Tipo de Telefono:</span>
                     </label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DdTelefonos" runat="server" class="form-control ns_">
                         <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-99">-- Selecciona --</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="1">Celular</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem value="2">Casa</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem value="3">Oficina</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <label class="control-label" for="txtRegRecNumeroTel">
                         <span class="form-text">Numero:</span>
                     </label>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegRecNumeroTel" runat="server" CssClass="form-control ns_" MaxLength="10" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" placeholder="Inserte el Numero de Contacto"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                     <label class="control-label" for="btnRegRecAgregarTel">
                         <br />
                     </label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRegRecAgregarTel" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Agregar" Style="float:right" OnClick="btnRegRecAgregarTel_Click"/>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <!--FIN PRIMERA FILA TELEFONOS-->
            <br />
            <!--INICIO PANEL DE TABLA TELEFONOS-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panelMuestra">
                        <div class="panel-body letra">
                            <!--INICO TABLA DE TELEFONOS-->

                            <div class="table-responsive" >
                            <asp:Literal ID="tablaTel" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                            </div>
                            <!--FIN TABLA DE TELEFONOS-->
                            <!--INICIO BOTONES DE TABLA TELEFONOS-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Modificar" Style="float:right"/>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Eliminar" Style="float:right"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--FIN BOTONES DE TABLA TELEFONOS-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>                  
            </div>
            <!--FIN PANEL DE TABLA TELEFONOS-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--FIN PANEL TELEFONOS-->
```

Here is the code from C# to insert in DB the new register

```cs
protected void btnRegRecAgregarTel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tipoNum = Int32.Parse(DdTelefonos.SelectedValue);
    int num = Int32.Parse(txtRegRecNumeroTel.Text);
    int empresa = Int32.Parse(DdlRegRecEmpresa.SelectedValue);
    int empleado = Int32.Parse(txtRegRecIdEmpleado.Text);
    this.GetData();
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog = GMG; Trusted_Connection = true; ");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(); 
        com.Connection = con; 
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
        com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO telefonos(TEL_ID_EMPRESA, TEL_ID_EMPLEADO, TEL_NUMERO_TELEFONO, TEL_TIPO_TELEFONO)" 
            +"VALUES(@TEL_ID_EMPRESA, @TEL_ID_EMPLEADO, @TEL_NUMERO_TELEFONO, @TEL_TIPO_TELEFONO); "; 

        com.Parameters.Add("@TEL_ID_EMPRESA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empresa;
        com.Parameters.Add("@TEL_ID_EMPLEADO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empleado;
        com.Parameters.Add("@TEL_NUMERO_TELEFONO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = num;
        com.Parameters.Add("@TEL_TIPO_TELEFONO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tipoNum;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        //Mostrar mensaje de que existio un error al crear el nuevo registro

    }
}
```

To load the table and connect with the DB I'm using this:

```cs
private void TablaTelefonosCarga()
{
    int tam = 1;
    DataTable dt = this.GetData();
    //Building an HTML string.
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    //Table start.
    html.Append("<table class='table table-striped table-bordered text-center'>" +
        "<thead>" +
        "<tr class='tituloTabla'>");

    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("#");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("Tipo Teléfono");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("Teléfono");
    html.Append("</th>");

    html.Append("</tr>" +
        "</thead>" +
        "<tbody> ");

    //Building the Data rows.
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {

        html.Append("<tr>");
        html.Append("<th scope='row' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>" + tam + "</th>");
        html.Append("<td><input type= 'checkbox' id='"+"checkbox"+tam+"'/></td>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<td>");
            html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
            html.Append("</td>");
        }

        html.Append("</tr>");
        tam++;
    }

    //Table end.
    html.Append("</tbody>" +
        "</table>");
    //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
    tablaTel.Text = html.ToString();
}
private DataTable GetData()
{
    int empresa = Int32.Parse(DdlRegRecEmpresa.SelectedValue);
    string empleado = (txtRegRecIdEmpleado.Text);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog = GMG; Trusted_Connection = true; "))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TEL_TIPO_TELEFONO,TEL_NUMERO_TELEFONO FROM telefonos WHERE TEL_ID_EMPLEADO = @TEL_ID_EMPLEADO"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TEL_ID_EMPLEADO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empleado;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: You need update html table after execute?

Comment: Yes, i need update

Comment: I think you might want to implement jQuery and use Ajax to update your table without destroying it.

Comment: When do you call your method **TablaTelefonosCarga**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after execute call method TablaTelefonosCarga();

```
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
TablaTelefonosCarga();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're calling to **TablaTelefonosCarga()** in Page_Load or in a method called by Page_Load itself, that means every change you make to the table will only be visible after load/reload page.

When you're pressing any button with **runat="server"** tag asp executes this button event handler after Page_Load, (Page_Load -> btnRegRecAgregarTel_Click, in this order). That means the table is showing before the new register is added to DB.

In order to reload the table, every time you modify it (add, update, delete) you must call **TablaTelefonosCarga()**.

In the code you're showing us, you must call **TablaTelefonosCarga()** once **btnRegRecAgregarTel_Click** is correctly executed, as evilGenius has indicated.